# How do I stop animations in a list from cancelling out one another in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some animations that are on spikes. The idea is they will fall on my Player's head and kill the player. The problem is, I have many of them in a row. I have put all those animations in a list and they all have the same script. I am using player prefs to communicate between scripts and the animations keep cancelling out one another. When I go on the gameobject, (on the ground and has a script that detects the player) The animation will play and kill the player. The problem is that when I go onto the next gameobject, the first anim is running and it just stops.

Here is my script that plays the anim:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pref_fall_spike : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public Animation anim;
    int get_spike = 0;
    public Animation anim;
    int get_spike_1 = 0;
    bool stop_anim = false;
    void Start()
    {
        //anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    public void AlertObservers(string message)
    {
        if (message.Equals("spike_animation_ended"))
        {

            stop_anim = true;
        }

    }
    void Update()
    {
        //anim.Play("real_spike_fall");
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("spike_fall") == 1)
        {
            
            anim.Play("real_spike_fall");

        }
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("spike_fall_1") == 1)
        {
            anim.Play("real_spike_fall_2");
        }
        //get_spike = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("spike_fall");
        if (stop_anim == true)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("spike_fall", 0);
            stop_anim = false;
            anim.Stop();
        }
        //if (get_spike == 1)
        //{
            
            //anim.Play();
        //}
    }
}
```

It seems to work when I stop the anim.Play() for the second animation, but the second animation also will not play...

Is there a way to fix this?